# Rename column values based on unique values of other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a data frame:

```
df = 

  id_easy   ordinal   weekday
0       0         1   Tuesday
1       0         2   Monday
2       0         3   Monday
3       1         1   Saturday
4       1         2   Tuesday
```

I want to check:

- In every unique `id_easy` value, rename `weekday` column to its value when `ordinal` is `1`.

Desired output:

```
df = 

  id_easy   ordinal   weekday
0       0         1   Tuesday       # as this is Tuesday
1       0         2   Tuesday       # so this became Tuesday as well
2       0         3   Tuesday       # so this became Tuesday as well
3       1         1   Saturday      # as this is Saturday
4       1         2   Saturday      # so this became Saturday as well
```

Comment: does the first row of each unique `id_easy` always have ordinal `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
df.weekday = df.groupby('id_easy')['weekday'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
   id_easy  ordinal   weekday
0        0        1   Tuesday
1        0        2   Tuesday
2        0        3   Tuesday
3        1        1  Saturday
4        1        2  Saturday
```